# Clickhouse creating view on cluster on non default database fails

Tags: go, clickhouse, clickhouse-client, clickhouse-go

I am trying to create a view on a clickhouse server that is ran in docker based on image clickhouse/clickhouse-server:22.8.13.20
I create a table in a database named X (not default), the connection url and client are connected to the correct database (Go code)
it properly creates a table on the clickhouse server and its replica statement -

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS statuses ON CLUSTER '{cluster}'
                    id Nullable(UUID),
                    team__id UUID,
                    event_id UUID,
                    domain__id Int64,
                    type String,
                    user_name String,
                    status String,
                    comment String,
                    time_utc DateTime
                ) 
                Engine = ReplicatedMergeTree('/clickhouse/tables/statuses', '{replica}')
                PARTITION BY (toYYYYMM(toDate(time_utc)))
                ORDER BY (status, time_utc)
```

However if when i try to create a view that references this table i get an error that table default.statuses does not exist (it exists at X.statuses and the clickhouse url in the client contains the database name and creates the table at X database)
create view statement -

```
CREATE OR REPLACE VIEW status_view ON CLUSTER '{cluster}' AS SELECT 
        statuses.status as status_status, 
        statuses.comment as status_comment, 
        statuses.event_id as status_event_id, 
        statuses.time_utc as status_time_utc
    FROM 
        statuses 
        JOIN (
        SELECT 
            statuses.event_id, 
            max(statuses.time_utc) AS time 
        FROM 
            statuses 
        GROUP BY 
            statuses.event_id
        ) AS last_status ON (
        (
            (
            statuses.event_id = last_status.event_id
            ) 
            AND (statuses.time_utc = last_status.time)
        )
        );
```

What could be the problem that the same client successfully creates a table in the correct database on both the server and its replica, however it cannot create a view

The go Client that executes the statement is a struct -

```
type Client struct {
    conn     *sql.DB
    replicas []string
    mode     string
}
```

and both views and tables are created in a function that calls c.conn.Exec(stmt) - where statements to create table and view are provided above

Answer (score 0):

Maybe, `ON CLUSTER` just not pass your current database from your connection to distributed DDL worker which executes separately. For 22.8, it doesn't reproduce on https://fiddle.clickhouse.com/9268aba0-36b8-48e4-8c3e-f306635c8433

Or possible, your `golang` code is wrong and your CREATE VIEW executed with `default` as `default_database` with different connection.

I would like suggest always use `database.table`  instead of `table` to avoid this kind of errors

Comment: I have thought about using the database name before table, however it means that the database name will be hardcoded in the statement. The thing is that the same Client creates the table properly in the correct database on the clickhouse server and its replica, but for some reason when I try to create a view it uses the default database